# XML processing, ordering and looping

Tags: php, arrays, xml, xslt, xmldom

I have been struggling for 10 days trying to render an XML feed:

http://feed.harjbains.gnomen-europe.com/xml-feed/

I have tried `simplexml`, `xmlDOM` and XSLT all have nuances. My programming skills are a bit challenged at the moment, I don't know if it's the drugs my doctor has given me or am I just getting old and should give up hacking code.

I have looked into multidimensional arrays, JSON and XML stylesheets, XSLT is very tedious does not like my XML and interferes with my stylesheet.

I want to be able to render the XML by displaying it either *date_updated* or *price* order, limiting the results by *status* and be able to limit the number of records to *n*.

Here is my code to place each element into an array however I cannot do any sorting like this.

```
<?php   
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://feed.harjbains.gnomen-europe.com/xml-feed/");

    $properties = $xml;

    $id             = array();
    $beds           = array();
    $baths          = array();
    $price          = array();
    $address1       = array();
    $area           = array();
    $postcode       = array();
    $date_updated   = array();
    $transaction    = array();
    $status         = array();
    $image          = array();
    $img            = array();
    $description    = array();

    $i=0;
    $totrecs=0;
    foreach ($properties as $property) {
        $i=$i+1;
        $address[$i]      = $property->address1;
        $id[$i]           = $property->id;
        $beds[$i]         = $property->beds;
        $baths[$i]        = $property->baths;
        $price[$i]        = $property->price;
        $address1[$i]     = $property->address1;
        $area[$i]         = $property->area;
        $postcode[$i]     = $property->postcode;
        $date_updated[$i] = $property->date_updated;
        $transaction[$i]  = $property->transaction;
        $status[$i]       = $property->status;
        $image[$i]        = $property->image;
        $description[$i]  = $property->description;
        $totrecs          = count($id);

        if(isset($property->image->img)) {
            //echo $address1[$i]."<BR>";
            $image[$i] = true;
            $x=0;
            foreach($property->image->img as $a) {
                $img[$i][$x]= $a;
                //echo $img[$i][$x]."<BR>";
                $x=$x+1;
            }
        } else {
           $image[$i] = false;
        }
    }
?>
```

Harj

Answer (score 1):

Reconsider XSLT as it maintains a [sort](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xslt/xslt_sort.htm) method. For demonstration, below transforms original XML feed to an XML with properties ordered by price in descending order, selects only specific elements, filters to first 5 (`&lt;` equivalent to `<`) and only elements with *status='Let'*.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file or embedded PHP string)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/properties">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="property[position() &lt; 6 and status='Let']">
            <xsl:sort select="translate(price, ',', '')" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="property">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:copy-of select="id|beds|baths|price|address1|area|postcode|date_updated|transaction|status|image|img|description"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**PHP**  *(be sure to have php-xsl extension enabled in .ini file)*

```
<?php

// LOAD XML FEED
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://feed.harjbains.gnomen-europe.com/xml-feed/");

// LOAD XSLT SCRIPT
$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('XSLT_Script.xsl');   // OR $xsl->loadXML($xslstring);

// INITIALIZE TRANSFORMER
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);    

// TRANSFORM SOURCE TO NEW TREE
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

// ECHO OUTPUT
echo $newXML;

// SAVE OUTPUT TO FILE
file_put_contents('Output.xml', $newXML);

?>
```

**Output**

```
<properties>
    <property>
        <id>1184</id>
        <beds>3</beds>
        <baths>3</baths>
        <image>
        </image>
        <price>695</price>
        <area>Wolverhampton</area>
        <address1>Park Hall Road</address1>
        <description>A vastly extended three bedroom semi-detached property. Just been totally re-furbished. Comprising of front reception room, extended through lounge, third room which can be used as fourth bedroom. This leads into a shower room which has WC and basin. Utility room with plumbing. Fitted kitchen with gas cooker and hob. To the first floor, master bedroom with en-suite. Two further double bedrooms and family bathroom. Rear garden and front garden with drive for off-road parking.</description>
        <postcode>WV4 5DU</postcode>
        <date_updated></date_updated>
        <transaction>2</transaction>
        <status>Let</status>
    </property>
    <property>
        <id>1176</id>
        <beds>3</beds>
        <baths>1</baths>
        <image>
        </image>
        <price>575</price>
        <area>Wolverhampton</area>
        <address1>Park Hall Road</address1>
        <description>A very well presented three bedroom semi-detached property which has been totally re-furbished. Living room, leading to dining room and fitted kitchen with cooker. Three bedrooms and new family bathroom with shower. New flooring and carpets throughout. Double glazed and gas central heated. Rear garden with patio, front garden with drive leading to garage. Available immediately.</description>
        <postcode>WV4 5DU</postcode>
        <date_updated></date_updated>
        <transaction>2</transaction>
        <status>Let</status>
    </property>
    <property>
        <id>1181</id>
        <beds>3</beds>
        <baths>1</baths>
        <image>
        </image>
        <price>550</price>
        <area>Willenhall</area>
        <address1>Westfield Road</address1>
        <description>A very well presented three bedroom semi-detached property. Front reception room, large fitted kitchen with dining area. To the first floor, three bedrooms and modern family bathroom with separate shower cubicle. Front garden with space for off-road parking, rear garden. Double glazed and central heated throughout. Available immediately.</description>
        <postcode>WV13 3JX</postcode>
        <date_updated></date_updated>
        <transaction>2</transaction>
        <status>Let</status>
    </property>
    <property>
        <id>1174</id>
        <beds>3</beds>
        <baths>1</baths>
        <image>
        </image>
        <price>550</price>
        <area>Willenhall</area>
        <address1>Sandringham Avenue</address1>
        <description>Three bedroom semi-detached property in popular residential area. Comprising of through lounge, fitted kitchen. Patio door to rear garden. Three bedrooms to first floor. Family bathroom with shower. Garage to side, front garden and off-road parking. Available immediately.</description>
        <postcode>WV12 5TF</postcode>
        <date_updated></date_updated>
        <transaction>2</transaction>
        <status>Let</status>
    </property>
    <property>
        <id>1177</id>
        <beds>3</beds>
        <baths>1</baths>
        <image>
        </image>
        <price>500</price>
        <area>Willenhall</area>
        <address1>Marshall Road</address1>
        <description>Three bedroom semi-detached property. Comprising of two reception rooms, fitted kitchen to ground floor. Three bedrooms and family bathroom to first floor. Double glazed and central heated throughout. Front and rear gardens. Available immediately.</description>
        <postcode>WV13 3PB</postcode>
        <date_updated></date_updated>
        <transaction>2</transaction>
        <status>Let</status>
    </property>
</properties>
```